# Calling a function when ng-repeat insert/remove items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a div that I need to calculate the height of this div based on a ng-repeat (adding or removing items).

Is there a way to have a callback for after ng-repeat inserts or removes items from the collection?
I know that it's possible after ng-repeat is finished, but I need after insert/ remove items.

Comment: If all items have an equals height, you could do it with a `$watch` on the *size* of the collection.

Comment: you can add a watch on the collection, and re-calculate when it changes.

Comment: The items don't have the same height

Comment: can you show what you have tried till now